# Why do I get "TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null" when trying to run webpack packaged node project

Tags: node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a simple application that is imported from webpack. The imported project exports a class like this...

```
export class BaseApp{...}

import { BaseApp } from "./MyClass"
import OtherThing from "./Other"
....
export { BaseApp, OtherThing }
```

Next I try to extend it in another node/express project...

```
import { BaseApp } from "@mine/util";

export class FullApp extends BaseApp{... }
```

I get...

```
class FullApp extends _mine_util__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["BaseA
pp"]{
                                                                         ^

TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
```

How do I extend a class I am importing from Webpack?

**Update** here is an example project that demonstrates the issue...

https://github.com/jrgleason/simple-webpack-node

Comment: You might not be importing `BaseApp` properly. However, we wouldn't be able to tell without knowing how it is exported.

Comment: What do you mean I am showing you how it is exported? Do I need to show it another way like after Webpack?

Comment: If I use it inside the lib that it is declared it works fine. So the actual declaration is fine.

Comment: Your are not showing how `./MyClass` exports the class.

Comment: Yeah I am I added that at the top and even then It is working in non node projects so I don't get it. I will made a simple project I will add that...

Comment: As I suspected. `export class BaseApp` is a named export, not a default export, so you have to import the class as `import {BaseClass} from './MyClass';`.

Comment: I am that was a typo adding the project now

Comment: See sample project

Answer (score 12):

Impossible to say for certain when there is clearly much more to the source. If anyone else sees this error, the first thing to look for is **circular dependencies**: a file depends on some other file that (likely indirectly) depends on the first. JS must start somewhere, will not be able to ensure that a file is defined at the time that another file needs it, and will not try to go back and fill in the blanks later.

If you have more than a couple import / require statements, I recommend periodically running a checker like [Madge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/madge) to find and optionally visualize any loops before they become hard to undo.

```sh
npm i --saveDev madge
node node_modules/madge/bin/cli.js --warning --circular --extensions js ./
```

Comment: Thank you, this madge tool is really useful to debug this obscure error message.